# How to open iGo via url scheme

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, url-scheme

Does anybody know url scheme for iGo app?
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/europe-igo-primo-app/id321933838?mt=8 
I have tried to find it on http://handleopenurl.com/scheme but there is none for iGo

Comment: It's possible they don't use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific question please try:

> igomyway://G47.498562;19.040910

**Warning:** have not checked with the new iOS versions so please take comments if it is not ok.

To check in the future other URL integration possibilites you can find here:

This site worked before, now it seems it has been shut down.
http://handleopenurl.com/

Comment: Doesn't work anymore.